# Tense choice for "being cheated on"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

I'm Japanese studying English. Am I interpreting each sentences below correctly?

1. She will claim she'll be cheated on. (She will say "I'm cheated on now.")
2. She will claim she is cheated on. (She will say "I was cheated on.")
3. She will claim she was cheated on. (She will say  "I was cheated on a long time ago")

Answer (score 1):

The tenses in your first two rephrasing are wrong, and while the tense in your third is correct, there is a qualifier that shouldn't be there.

> She will claim she'll be cheated on.

At some point in the future, she will claim she *will* be cheated on.

> She will say, "I will be cheated on."

She will make a declaration about a future event.

---

> She will claim she is cheated on.

At some point in the future, she will claim she *is* being cheated on.

> She will say, "I am being cheated on."

She will make a declaration about a current event.

---

> She will claim she was cheated on.

At some point in the future, she will claim she *was* cheated on.

> She will say, "I was cheated on."

She will make a declaration about a past event.

The original phrasing makes no mention of it having been "a long time ago," so she will not say that.